# return type of public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()?

Tags: c#, ienumerator

To implement collection, I have to complete GeEnumerator(). But the return type of this function is IEnumerator. How can it be done ?
For example..

```
class MyList : IEnumerable, IEnumerator
{
    private int[] array;
    int positino = -1;        
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < array.Length; ++i)
        {
              yield return array[i];
        }
    }
}
```

array[i] is integer not IEnumerator type. How can this function return integer?

Comment: I think this code compiles and works. Do you understand in principle what yield return does? What is the problem that you are having trouble with?

Comment: You should read about `yield` in C#: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can this function return integer

It doesn't, it `yield return`s an integer. This means that it can be compiled into a method that returns `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerable<int>`, `IEnumerator` or `IEnumerator<int>` depending on which your method says it returns.

The `yield` keyword is a convenience that allows for the creation of an enumerator with the appropriate `MoveNext()`, `Current`, and `Dispose`, and if it's an enumerable then the appropriate `GetEnumerator` too.

Looking at your method:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
  for(int i = 0 ; i < array.Length; ++i)
  {
      yield return array[i];
  }
}
```

Then this is something that compiles, though to really work it needs more to actually assign something to `array`.

When we compile it, it has the same result as if we'd written:

```
private class En : IEnumerator<object>
{
  private object _current;
  private int _state;
  public MyList _this;
  public int _index;
  public bool MoveNext()
  {
    int state = _state;
    switch(state)
    {
      case 0:
        _state = -1;
        _index = 0;
        break;
      case 1:
        _state = -1;
        if(++_index >= _this.array.Length)
          return false;
        break;
      default:
        return false;
    }
    _current = _this.array[_index];
    _state = 1;
    return true;
  }
  public object Current
  {
    get { return _current; }
  }
  public void Reset()
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException();
  }
  public void Dispose()
  {
  }
  object IEnumerator.Current
  {
    get { return _current; }
  }
  public En(int state)
  {
    _state = state;
  }
}
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
  var en = new En(0);
  en._this = this;
  return en;
}
```

The main difference is that `En` and its fields would all have names that aren't valid C# names but are valid .NET names, so it can't clash with any names a programmer used.

This has a bit more to it than it needs. It implements `IEnumerator<object>` as well as `IEnumerator`, but then that means the compiler can just have logic for `IEnumerable<T>` and use `object` for the `T` for the non-generic type rather than having separate logic. `_state` is more complicated than necessary, but if the `yield`-using method was more complicated than a single loop, then different values for `_state` would allow it to keep track of which part of that `yield`-using method it was corresponding with.

In all it's done a good job of implementing `IEnumerator`. It's a bit larger than if you were to hand-code one (and obviously larger than if you'd just used `return array.GetEnumerator();`), but not a lot larger, but conversely the `yield`-using method is a lot shorter and often these methods are simpler. This is even more so in cases where e.g. you have a `using` block in the `yield`-using method, which gets turned into the appropriate clean-up in the enumerator's `Dispose()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the generics and IEnumerable int

```
public class MyList : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public MyList()
    {
        array = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    }

    private int[] array;
    int positino = -1;        
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < array.Length; ++i)
        {
              yield return array[i];
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that in this specific case you can "cheat" and not really implement `GetEnumerator()`, using the array implementation:

```
public class MyList : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public MyList()
    {
        array = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    }

    private int[] array;

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<int>)array).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```